# Styling a jsx element in react

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have this line of code in my project that generates a certain percentage and shows it on the dashboard.

```
   <text
          className="netProfit-circle-text"
          x="50%"
          y="50%"
          dy=".2em"
          textAnchor="middle"
        >
          {`${this.state.percentage}%`}
        </text>
```

What I want to do is to be able to style the "%" and change its size using CSS. How can I do this? 
Thanks in advance.

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `tspan` element to wrap the `%` part. The `tspan` element can be styled to look visually different than the rest of the `text`'s content. [Link to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/tspan)

`<tspan>%</tspan>`

Answer (score 1):

You can simply wrap the `%` in a `<span>` with a class:

```
<text
    className="netProfit-circle-text"
    x="50%"
    y="50%"
    dy=".2em"
    textAnchor="middle"
>
    {this.state.percentage}
    <span class="percentage">%</span>
</text>
```

and then add some styles to it:

```css
span.percentage {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Nothing is rendered when I do this. The percentage sign disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

yes, it's possible. You can render it as two different `jsx` elements like this:

```
    <text
      className="netProfit-circle-text"
      x="50%"
      y="50%"
      dy=".2em"
      textAnchor="middle"
    >
      <text>{this.state.percentage}</text>
      <text className="per-color">%</text>
    </text>
```

Working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-leftpad-lue55.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But unfortunately, it shows nothing when I do this.

Comment: Here's a working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-leftpad-lue55.

Comment: Thanks a lot. All is well now.